# When searching for my own site on Google, I see spam for the page title and description

Tags: seo, search-results

When I do a Google search for my website "Mike Grossman Consulting" the result with my URL mikegrossmanconsulting.com contains spam like information. (The page title and description contain spam phrases.) I've attached a screen grab with the spam text highlighted. I checked on my website and there are no references to "Plavix" anywhere. Please let me know how to get rid of the spam.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you see spam in Google search results for the text on your site, that usually means that your site has been hacked.  Hackers often change sites to show spam just to Googlebot and to users from Google so that it is harder for you to notice that your own site is hacked.

Google usually notices these things and starts showing a "hacked site" warning in the search results and would contact you through Google Search Console if you have signed up for it.  Google has a fairly comprehensive guide for cleaning up hacked sites.   See: https://www.google.com/webmasters/hacked/?hl=en